# I want to know the meaning of this function(.on()) in detail

Tags: javascript, node.js

i dont know what is 'data' and req.on() method, please help me

```
http.createServer( (req, res) => { .....

if( req.method === 'POST') {
if( req.url ==='/user') {
let body ='';
req.on('data', (data) => {
body += data;
});
```

Comment: it is the event name, you can find more here https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Answer (score 1):

Basically a user can send data to an HTTP server by connecting to it, send the date and then disconnect. this works for a small amount of data. by this kind of request when the user sends an HTTP request and when `http.createServer( (req, res) => {}`  gets called, you'll have a complete body and can access it in `req.body`, in other words, you've got the whole data sent by the user.

But sometimes the user wants to send a huge file(a big image, video, etc), the problem is, that it's problematic to send that huge data with a single request, instead, the user sends the data with a stream of data chunks. the user connects to the server and `http.createServer( (req, res) => {}` gets called, then the user starts to send the data in chunks, now with every chunk of data that is being sent and is being received by the server, `req.on('data', (data) => {})` gets called, and it adds the received data to the body of the request. when the streams are finished, you'll have a complete body that contains that big file or any kind of big data that the user sent, and after finishing streams, the user disconnects from the server.

Comment: I'm not familiar with English, and I don't understand javascript well because it hasn't been a month since I studied it. I'll read it until I get it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The `req.on` method is part of node's Event Emitter model. It provides methods to bind functions to certain events (`on` in this case) and ways to dispatch events to that functions

The `data` event is one of those examples. It is dispatched when there's data available in the buffer for the request to read, basically.

You can find more information on Event Emitters [here](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) and about the http events, you can find it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html).

Comment: I'm not familiar with English, and I don't understand javascript well because it hasn't been a month since I studied it. I'll read it until I get it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The `req.on` method is a function which allows to attach event listener for the event named which is passed as the first argument [emitter.on](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_eventname_listener).

the `req` object is type of `http.ClientRequest` which extends the [EventEmitte](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) which as some function which are related to **Publish–subscribe pattern** [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern).

in your case which i repeat bellow

```
req.on('data', (data) => {
    body += data;
});
```

You are attaching a listener which will be executed every time the `req` object dispatch in their internal work flow the **data** event.

Comment: I'm not familiar with English, and I don't understand javascript well because it hasn't been a month since I studied it. I'll read it until I get it. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. which other language are comfortable with